# how to select multiple user Access in joomla zoo item?

Tags: joomla

I need to select multiple in joomla "access" users form field in zoo items, is this possible?

[click the screenshot to see the hi-lighted area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7iZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select multiple access levels; however, you can accomplish the same concept by creating a new user access level and assigning the multiple user groups to that access group.